# How can I manually edit the list of recently opened files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I rely heavily on the `File: Open Recent…` command to open frequently used files, but yesterday my local Google Drive folder got moved to a new location and now I can no longer access any of the files in that folder through the Open Recent panel because the paths don't match.

The fix would be as simple as replacing "/Google Drive/" with "/Google Drive/My Drive/" but I have no idea what file contains the list of files that appears in the recently opened panel.

I'm assuming it's somewhere in `~/Library/Application Support/Code` but not sure where.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was wondering the same thing the other day and found this while searching for a solution, so I took some time to investigate it today.
It's been a a few weeks since you posted, so hopefully this will still be of help to you.
Also, I'm using Windows and I'm not familiar with macOS, but I think it should be easy enough adjust the solution.

**Location of settings**
Those setting are stored in the following file: `%APPDATA%\Code\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb`.
The file is an sqlite3 database, which is used as a key-value store.
It has a single table named `ItemTable` and the relevant key is `history.recentlyOpenedPathsList`.

The value has the following structure:

```json
{
  "entries": [
    {
      "folderUri": "/path/to/folder",
      "label": "...",
      "remoteAuthority": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

To view the current list, you can run the following command:

```
sqlite3.exe -readonly "%APPDATA%\Code\User\globalStorage\state.vscdb" "SELECT [value] FROM ItemTable WHERE [key] = 'history.recentlyOpenedPathsList'" | jq ".entries[].label"
```

**Modifying the settings**
Specifically, I was interested in changing the way it's displayed (the label), so I'll detail how I did that, but it should be just as easy to update the path.
Here's the Python code I used to make those edits:

```py
import json, sqlite3

# open the db, get the value and parse it
db = sqlite3.connect('C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb')
history_raw = db.execute("SELECT [value] FROM ItemTable WHERE  [key] = 'history.recentlyOpenedPathsList'").fetchone()[0]
history = json.loads(history_raw)

# make the changes you'd like
# ...

# stringify and update
history_raw = json.dumps(history)
db.execute(f"UPDATE ItemTable SET [value] = '{history_raw}' WHERE key = 'history.recentlyOpenedPathsList'")
db.commit()
db.close()
```

**Code references**
For reference (mostly for my future self), here are the relevant source code areas.
The settings are read [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/4caf63f62e97df8af4eb88259073dc5d2dceeff7/src/vs/platform/workspaces/electron-main/workspacesHistoryMainService.ts#L226).
The `File->Open Recent` uses those values as-is (see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/cd5bde189683ca1b2b0896803e7684e88f3e4dd4/src/vs/workbench/browser/parts/titlebar/menubarControl.ts#L310)).
However when using the `Get Started` page, the `Recents` area is populated [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9d1c2920c0d4a433af493b3777b0e8d45088299b/src/vs/workbench/contrib/welcomeGettingStarted/browser/gettingStarted.ts#L846). In the `Get Started`, the label is presented in a slightly different way:
[vscode snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQGKi.png)
The folder name is the link, and the parent folder is the the text beside it.
This is done by the [splitName](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/9d1c2920c0d4a433af493b3777b0e8d45088299b/src/vs/base/common/labels.ts#L441) method.

**Notes**

- Before messing around with the settings file, it would be wise to back it up.
- I'm not sure how vscode handles and caches the settings, so I think it's best to close all vscode instances before making any changes.
- I haven't played around with it too much, so not sure how characters that need to be json-encoded or html-encoded will play out.
- Keep in mind that there might be some state saved by other extensions, so if anything weird happens, blame it on that.
- For reference, I'm using vscode 1.74.2.

**Links**

- [SQLite command-line tools](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html)
- [jq - command-line JSON processor](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/)

Comment: Very cool.  Thank you.  It's somewhat annoying that the VSCode built-in Settings Sync doesn't at least have the option to replicate this recently opened files list.  I use the recently opened file list ALL the time to switch between several customer projects setup via remote SSH connections and whatnot.  It's a pain to setup all that on a fresh VSCode install.

Comment: Where would it be on a Mac? I can't find it

Answer (score 1):

To add to Eli Finkel's answer, the location on Mac is `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/state.vscdb`